# Distribution of area of a circle

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

The radius of a disc is measured approximately. Assuming that the measurements are uniformly distributed over $[a,b]$, find the distribution of the area of the disc.

I do not manage to get the right answer. Can anyone solve the problem up to the end? :))

Comment: What answer did you get, and more importantly how did you approach this?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I defined limits for the area, the tried to compute the the probability that the are is less or equal y, for y belonging [pi*a^2; pi*b^2], but I do not get the answer which is provided by my professor.

Comment: If you want to get the character $\pi$, you have to type \pi, with a dollar sign ($) before and after it.

Comment: @bubba, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline/hint:

1. What is the relationship between the radius and the area?
   $$A = \pi R^2.$$
   They tell us that $R\sim\text{unif}(a,b)$.
2. Now, I need to find the distribution of $A$ using that relationship. What do I do?

Comment: 2. So P{`πR^2<=y`} should be computed, right?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't do that. That's not how I solve it. I would use a change of variable
$$f_A(a) = \frac{f_R(\sqrt{a/\pi})}{\left|\frac{da}{dr}\right|}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this way it's resolved immediately. But I guess regardless the way of solving, I should be getting the same answer. What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Are you saying that doing it my way worked but your way did not?

Comment: Yes, I that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure because I don't actually want to work it out. Haha. They reason is probably because what you computed sounds like the CDF of $A$. If you take the derivative of your answer, it might be the correct answer. That's my guess. Also, a check mark would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So the answer is $(x/$\pi$)^(1/2) - a/(b-a)$ for [$\pi$$a^2$; $\pi$$b^2$]